# React Native: can't get release bundle because react-native-screens kotlin error?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

When doing a gradlew clean assembleRelease to get .aab file of my react-native appI get the following:

```
> Task :react-native-screens:compileReleaseKotlin FAILED
e: org.jetbrains.kotlin.util.KotlinFrontEndException: Exception while analyzing expression in (15,47) in C:/xampp/htdocs/WOO!/node_modules/react-native-screens/android/src/main/java/com/swmansion/rnscreens/SearchViewFormatter.kt

Attachments:
causeThrowable
java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\xampp\htdocs\WOO!\node_modules\react-native-screens\android\build\intermediates\compile_r_class_jar\release\R.jar!/node_modules/react-native-screens/android/build/intermediates/compile_r_class_jar/release/R.jar!/com/swmansion/rnscreens/R.class
```

And:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':react-native-screens:compileReleaseKotlin'.
> A failure occurred while executing org.jetbrains.kotlin.compilerRunner.GradleCompilerRunnerWithWorkers$GradleKotlinCompilerWorkAction
```

It seems .jar file seems missing, this started happening after I changed my app package name (I think...)

I tried upgrading kotlin version to 1.8.0 inside build.gradle but still getting the same error.

My package.json file

```
"react-native": "0.68.5",
"react-native-screens": "^3.19.0"
```

I have been stuck with this for a while, I can't uninstall react-native-screens library since react-narive-navigation has a dependency on it (it seems)

Comment: Just linking an issue form `react-native-screens` repo: https://github.com/software-mansion/react-native-screens/issues/1716

Comment: yeah, that's actually me